# Can't access the factory recovery after installing ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

I installed ubuntu alongside XP on a dell laptop which had a recovery partition for re-installing XP. XP and ubuntu both worked OK.
Now I want to see the laptop so I need to restore the laptop to factory state but i can't access the recovery by pressing CTRL-F11
Any help will be appreciated.
Hamid

Comment: Did you erased other partitions to make room for Ubuntu?.

Comment: You may consider to add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (*edit*) so  we can see if this partition still exists.

Comment: No updates...localized

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I noticed a "Dell recovery" package in the Software Center. There's a review comment that it doesn't work with 11.10 but that might be a case of pilot error. In the Software Center page for the Dell package there's a "Developer Site Link" that goes to linux.dell.com. Perhaps you can find help that way.